# PlayOnLinux not working with on wxPython 4.1.0 - ImportError: No Module named wxversion, needs to be wx.version instead

Tags: python, wine, playonlinux, gtk3, wxpython

The latest version of wxPython doesn't support the wxversion module. Instead the information is available as wx.version.

***Is there any suggested work around to this?* Thanks!**

> My environment is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, pyenv, python 3.8.3, python 2.7.18,  wxPython 4.1.0

```
$ apt-cache policy playonlinux
playonlinux:
  Installed: 4.3.4-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4.3.4-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ which playonlinux
/usr/bin/playonlinux

# *** note: i'm using pyenv ***

$ pyenv local 2.7.18

$ which python2
/home/dever/.pyenv/shims/python2

$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.18

$ pyenv local 3.8.3

$ which python3
/home/dever/.pyenv/shims/python3

$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.3
```

**Installed Python 3.8.3 configuration has wxPython 4.1.0**

```
$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul 16 2020, 20:35:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> print(wx.version)
<function version at 0x7ff77d3cbd30>
>>> print(wx.version())
4.1.0 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.4
>>> quit()
```

**Consequently, the playonlinux command fails with this error:**

```
$ playonlinux
Looking for python... 3.8.3 - skipped
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.18 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.18 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

**NOTE: For those struggling to install wxPython on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** due to GTK+ error `*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...`

Try this command (found here: https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/)

```
pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04 wxPython
```

For additional context also see: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/where-to-obtain-wxversion-py/28752

#### playonlinux installed initially as follows, but reinstalled with standard repository on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (i upgraded from 19.10):

> The version of playonlinux I'm running is for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Version) downloaded from here: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

```
For the Bionic version

Type the following commands:
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_bionic.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

### Maybe playonlinux is superseded by the flatpak version?

Looking at the Github link on https://www.playonlinux.com takes you to https://github.com/PhoenicisOrg/ which suggest that perhaps the solution is to migrate to the flatpak version:

https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.phoenicis.playonlinux

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy playonlinux`, `which playonlinux`, `which python2`, `which python3` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1259914/edit).

Comment: @N0rbert i've added then environmental information to the beginning of the question - Thanks!

Comment: Then yours python venv created problems. Try with normal system-wide python.

Comment: i don't see how that could be related to the wxversion module not existing and being retired in the latest version of wxPython. The error message doesn't indicate a python version  environment problem, but rather a wxPython version incompatibility IMO

Comment: The PlayOnLinux depends on Python 2. Install all the stuff using APT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer: The problem is related to *pyenv*, make sure `system` is first choice in global configuration: `pyenv global system` or set the python version for the current shell with `pyenv shell system`. If you use `global` you only have set it once.

**Short explanation:** Use `pyenv global system (2nd) (3rd)...` to ensure that playonlinux finds the right python; where (2nd) and (3rd) are pyenv version numbers for your installed interpreters.

**Long explanation:** After getting the curtain rolled back with the really helpful posts by @N0bert, I've discovered that in my case the problem is **pyenv related**.

Specifically, I can resolve my issue by using the `pyenv global` command and making `system` first as follows (Note: the command you execute will depend on the versions of python you have installed):

```
pyenv global system 3.8.3 2.7.18 anaconda3-2019.10
```

Investigating the problem more, I reviewed the following files:

- `/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python`
- `/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py`

I made my own copies of these to understand the error better. It turns out the **wxversion error** is really misleading, the real problem is finding the right python shell to run. `playonlinux` depends on the system python.

Initially I thought that running the `pyenv local system` would solve the problem, but because of how pyenv works this was not the case.

To ensure that `/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python` resolves to the system installed python, you must make sure that `pyenv global` is set with `system` as the first choice.

*Many thanks to @N0rbert !!*

Comment: It is really great that you found the root of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply install latest PlayOnLinux 4.3.4 from the official repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install --reinstall playonlinux=4.3.4-1ubuntu1
```

and it will depend on Python 2 as it [is designed to be](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/playonlinux).

---

The complete command to install PlayOnLinux with dependencies is below:

```
sudo apt-get install cabextract curl fonts-wine gcc-10-base:i386 \
glib-networking:i386 gsfonts gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 \
icoutils imagemagick imagemagick-6-common imagemagick-6.q16 \
intel-media-va-driver:i386 jq libaa1:i386 libaom0:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 \
libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libatomic1:i386 \
libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 \
libavc1394-0:i386 libavcodec58:i386 libavutil56:i386 libblkid1:i386 \
libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 \
libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386 \
libcdparanoia0:i386 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcrypt1:i386 \
libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 \
libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 \
libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 \
libexpat1:i386 libfaudio0:i386 libffi7:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 \
libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc-s1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 \
libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 \
libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 \
libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 \
libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0:i386 \
libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 \
libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 \
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 \
libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 \
libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 \
libhogweed5:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu66:i386 libidn2-0:i386 \
libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11:i386 libilmbase24 \
libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 \
libjq1 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 \
libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 \
libllvm10:i386 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 \
libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 \
libmount1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libmysqlclient21:i386 \
libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6:i386 libnetpbm10 libnettle7:i386 \
libnghttp2-14:i386 libnuma1:i386 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libonig5 \
libopenal1:i386 libopenexr24 libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 \
libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 \
libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpci3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 \
libpcre2-8-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libperl5.30:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 \
libpng16-16:i386 libproxy1v5:i386 libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386 \
libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libraw1394-11:i386 \
libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 librtmp1:i386 \
libsamplerate0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 \
libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsensors5:i386 \
libshine3:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsnappy1v5:i386 \
libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp35:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 \
libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-4:i386 libssl1.1:i386 \
libstb0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libswresample3:i386 libsystemd0:i386 \
libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 \
libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libudev1:i386 \
libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386 \
libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2:i386 libva-x11-2:i386 libva2:i386 \
libvdpau1:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 \
libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386 libvulkan1:i386 libwavpack1:i386 \
libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 \
libwebp6:i386 libwebpmux3:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine:i386 \
libwrap0:i386 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libx11-6:i386 \
libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-155:i386 libx265-179:i386 libxau6:i386 \
libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 \
libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 \
libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 \
libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 \
libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 \
libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 \
libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386 \
libzvbi0:i386 mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 \
mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 netpbm ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 \
playonlinux python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python2 python2-minimal \
python2.7 python2.7-minimal va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 \
wine wine32:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

(from command above you can see that two wx-related packages - `python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion` are listed)

Comment: The error suggest that the the issue is wxversion is not found, this has been replaced by wx.version in the latest version of wxPython v4. I could not get wxPython installed with pip until I provided the -f option for the .whl as shown above (due to gtk+ install errors). I don't think there is a whl file for an earlier version of wxPython available that would have the older wxversion module.

Comment: I ran the commands you suggest successfully and get the same error: `Looking for python2... 2.7.18 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests`

Comment: IMHO you have created special additional problems by using pip on top of APT and by using local python on top of system-wide python. Switching to system-wide python will fix the issue. I have just installed PoL on normal 20.04 LTS with normal python, I have no issues here.

Comment: Which version of wxPython did you install and how do you install that without using pip? If you're not installing wxPython 4 please share the version and the command. Thank You!!

Comment: /usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py didn't even run with the system python until adding this check `os.environ.has_key("POL_OS")`. So that no longer fails. I suspect that /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python is doing something that is incompatible with pyenv. I will investigate further. I need pyenv as a developer. You can easily switch back to the system python, but doing that doesn't solve the issue. Will try to diagnose further. It appears I have everything installed by apt `sudo apt search wxpython` correctly.

Comment: @N0bert you were correct in thinking it was a pyenv related issue. After digging in I have a solution. Using the 'pyenv global' command you make 'system' first. This causes  the find_python test to succeed. For my installed python versions on 20.04 LTS, the command is `pyenv global system 3.8.3 2.7.18 anaconda3-2019.10`. I think the wxversion error was completely a red herring. I'd guess those scripts could return a better error, but that's a thought for another day. Thanks so much for your help!!! could not have gotten there without it. I'll try to post an answer to explain this better.