# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full

Tags: python, playonlinux, wxpython

I am trying to run PlayOnLinux and it is not starting, while running the same from terminal it is showing the following error,

```
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
  File "/home/sohel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/home/sohel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full
failed tests
Looking for python... 3.8.8 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
  File "/home/sohel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/home/sohel/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.18 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.18 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I have tried to install `wxPython` as well but facing following issue,

```
    *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
    *** exact error that occurred. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
    configure: error:
    The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
    ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
    installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
    and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
    libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
    --libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.
```

I have tried to reinstall the same using `apt` and manually installed using `deb` package but no luck.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259914/playonlinux-not-working-with-on-wxpython-4-1-0-importerror-no-module-named-wx

Comment: Try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273517/importerror-libsdl2-2-0-so-0-in-wxpython-wx-adv/59277031#59277031]

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I managed to find the link from @Esther comment to install wxPython, but still after installing it I am not able to import wx, Now it is giving me another error ```from ._core import *
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full
```

Comment: did you change the `pyvenv` config as directed in the accepted answer to the question I linked?